# Is there a way to attach a status to FBSDKShareContent

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift

I need to attach a description or status when users share photos videos to apps this is the code I have right now:

for video:

```
let fbVideo: FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo()

fbVideo.videoURL = self.videoUrl!
var content: FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
content.video = fbVideo

FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: nil)
```

and for images:

```
    let photo : FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
    photo.image = self.image
    photo.userGenerated = true
    var content: FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
    content.photos = [photo]
    FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: nil)
```

can't seem a way to attach the text status to the FBSDKShareContent

Comment: You are __not allowed__ to do that – the user has to type the message/caption himself. You should go read the [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Comment: Yeh the user does type it himself but the issue is I don't know how to attach it to the photo/video I upload.

Comment: That would still be considered 'pre-filling'. The user has to type the message directly into the Share Dialog, not before hand.

Comment: How does instagram do this then? I am doing the same exact setup as them